# Scrapy shell works but actual script returns 404 error

Tags: python-2.7, http-status-code-404, scrapy

```
scrapy shell http://www.zara.com/us
```

Returns a correct 200 code

```
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: zara)
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'zara.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['zara.spiders'], 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'zara', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'USER_AGENT': 'zara (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'}
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.zara.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.zara.com/us/> from <GET http://www.zara.com/us>
2017-01-05 18:34:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.zara.com/us/> (referer: None) ['cached']
```

But my actual py script causes a 404 error when I try to enter www.zara.com/us. If I use wwww.zara.com, the page returns a 200 but when I try to do it with the country specific site, it returns a 404...

```
class ZaraSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "zara-us"
    allowed_domain = ['www.zara.com/us']
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.zara.com/us"
    ]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    # navigating main page
    def parse(self, response):

        # get 1st 2 category listing in navigation sidebar
        categories = response.xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/ul/li')
        collections = categories[0].xpath('a//text()').extract()
        yield ProductItem(collection=collections[0])
```

Typing in terminal: 
`scrapy crawl zara-us`

```
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: zara)
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'zara.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['zara.spiders'], 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'zara', 'USER_AGENT': 'zara (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'}
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-05 18:45:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-05 18:45:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.zara.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2017-01-05 18:45:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.zara.com/us> (referer: None) ['cached']
2017-01-05 18:45:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.zara.com/us> (referer: None)
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy by default for every new projects turns on `ROBOTS_TXT_OBEY` to True, which means before your spider can scrape anything it checks websites `robots.txt` file for what is allowed and disallowed to be scraped.

To disable this simply delete the setting `ROBOTS_TXT_OBEY` from `settings.py` file.

See more [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)