# Scrapy Access Denied crawling the head of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I wanna crawler a website, but I got the next error:

```
'<head>\n<title>Access Denied</title>\n</head>'
```

I just trying in the console:

```
scrapy shell https://www.zara.com/es/en/
response.css("head").get()
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Is related to the User-Agent? Does the website have an anti-crawling method? How can crawl this website?

Comment: Seems to be working in scrapy shell for me.

Comment: I got the same error. I think its expected as the site requires credentials.

Comment: @AaronS do you have something special in your settings.py?

Comment: @Sree do you mean to be login in the website?

Comment: Here's the output from my cmd from starting a blank project to getting the html. No specific settings changes. If anyone can see something I've missed let me know! Very strange. https://pastebin.com/yjUxC89B

Comment: @AaronS https://pastebin.com/kuFiW6ub I see differences with something robots.txt and this part {'BOT_NAME': 'zara1',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'zara1.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['zara1.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'zara1 (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'} but I do not what to do

Comment: @AaronS in the settings.py do you have this value ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False or do you have it in TRUE?

Comment: It was a new scrapy project. The pastebin has exactly what I did from the command line. You can see from the output that ROBOTSTXT_OBEY is set to True. I'm not sure why 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', is in the output because it's not within my settings.py. https://pastebin.com/Z5GD56GM for my settings. I'm not using a VPN either.

Comment: For some reason I must of deleted the hash from the settings py of the user agent when i set the project up. I just created a new project and got the error you had except the difference was I didn't have a user agent set in the new project. Once I set the useragent I got the response you needed. See answer below.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497697/scrapy-shell-works-but-actual-script-returns-404-error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217795/discussion-between-aarons-and-eric-bellet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `USER_AGENT = 'zara (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'` in settings.py. Solves the issue. You could put your own user agent if you like also.

Comment: Yes, It was the USER_AGENT. I changed to my previous project but it does not work, so I create a new project and I change that and now It works. Thanks